# Symfony Insight : How to prevent the "no entity manager in parameters" warning for a CustomIdGenerator?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I use SymfonyInsight in a gitlab-ci to improve the code quality of my application. In this app, I need to use a CustomIdGenerator for my entities.

In my analysis, I got a warning error : The Doctrine Entity Manager should not be passed as an argument. This error is detected for the method called "generate" used by the CustomIdGenerator.

```
<?php


namespace MyApp\Generator;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AbstractIdGenerator;

class IDGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{

    /**
     * Generates an identifier for an entity.
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param object|null $entity
     * @return int
     * @throws \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException
     * @throws \ReflectionException
     */
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $class = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor(get_class($entity))->getName();

        $res = <My own logic>

        return $res;
    }
}
```

My Entity :

```
<?php


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_table")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_unique", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="IDGenerator")
     */
    private $id;
```

Is there a way to prevent SymfonyInsight to trigger this error only in this case ?

Comment: I suppose you could try using EntityManagerInterface.  Just a guess.  Probably generate even more messages.

Comment: The docs might also be helpful: https://insight.symfony.com/what-we-analyse

Comment: @Cerad I have already check the documentation but I didn't find any information about this problem in particular

Comment: Strange.  I would have expected that clicking on the "The Doctrine Entity Manager should not be passed as an argument" under Architecture would have offered at least some insight.  I don't have an Insight account so the link is blocked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with the Symfony on Slack community (https://symfony.com/slack), the fact is that we can not prevent this error with code. The only solution is to prevent scanning for the folder where the CustomIdGenerator is located.

https://insight.symfony.com/docs/how-to/ignore-a-specific-directory.html